# How to achieve the following layout on Android

Tags: android, layout

I'm trying to build the following layout on Android without any success.

I want a text to be displayed on my screen. It can take the whole width, but must be centered horizontally.

On the same line, on the right side of the screen I want to display a small layout. It shouldn't impact the horizontal centering of the main text and the main text shouldn't be visible behind the layout displayed on the right.

I cannot use a hard color for my layout background as it's displayed on a transparent background over a bitmap...

Any idea on how to achieve this ?

I can either use a RelativeLayout in which case the main text isn't centered based on the middle of the screen (it takes the right layout width into account)
Or the text is displayed behind the right layout...

Edit:
Here is one of my test

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:text="very looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong text"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:padding="3dp"
                    android:visibility="visible" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="24dp"
                        android:layout_height="24dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                        android:filter="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/device_access_time" />
                    <Spinner
                        android:layout_width="20dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />
                </LinearLayout>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: show diagram at least

Comment: what does it mean "main text shouldn't be visible behind the layout displayed on the right."

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how I can can explain it better. I just want to center a texte horizontally and to display a small layout on the same row aligned to the right of the screen. My layout shows some content on a transparent background and I don't want to see the centered text behind the right layout

Answer (score 0):

RelativeLayouts adhere to the principle of z-indexes, so if you put the right-aligned layout first, the centered text view will be drawn correctly on top.

Comment: I want the centered text to be displayed behind the right layout and to be invisible behind it. I put the TextView section first in the xml but I can still see it behind the right layout

Comment: Does the bitmap stretch across the width of the RelativeLayout or is just under the right-aligned layout?

Comment: Everything is displayed over a bitmap displayed on the whole screen. I just talked about this to avoid hacks like using a solid background on the right layout to 'hide' the text displayed behind

Comment: I gotcha. Your original post made it sound like the textview should be visible on top of the layout. You're going to have to measure the width of the screen and right-aligned layout after it's rendered and then set padding on the textview to push it over to appear as though it's centered.

Comment: Or, depending on the complexity of the bitmap background, add that as the background of the right-aligned layout. Is it a simple bitmap or something complex?

Comment: It's a blurred bitmap. I was looking for a 'simple' resource file solution in order to avoid measuring the right layout. I guess I won't be able to avoid this...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100079/discussion-between-airowe-and-user1026605).